# If the combobox text is equal to text in a column list, then follow hyperlink in cell to the right

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a list of File descriptions on a sheet which correspond to the drop down list in a combobox. I would like a code such that when the user selects any item in this drop down list, the code identifies the matching text in the column and then follows the link in the cell to the right for the description.

This is the Code I have so far:

```
    Private Sub Open_Button_Click()

Select Case OI_FileName

    Case Is = OI_FileName.Value = Sheets("File_Paths").Range("Description").Value

        With Open_Button

            For Each Cell In Range("Description")
                If (Selection.OI_FileName = Cell.Value) Then Exit For
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
                        Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
            Return
        End With

End Select

    End Sub
```

I'm not sure it is working properly because VBA displays: Compile Error: End With without With.

Any help you could offer would be much appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure if this code will work or not as I haven't looked through it closely, but you are missing i) "End If" which seems like it should appear immediately before "Return" ii) "Next Cell" which seems like it should appear immediately below the added "End If"

Comment: Also, it's unclear what "Return" is supposed to be doing.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the "Return should be there either. The idea is that no matter what the user selects from the combobox, the code searches for a match in all the cells in the Range("Description").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.  The With Statement was unneccessary.

```
Private Sub Open_Button_Click()
Dim StrFilePaths As String
Dim CurrFileName As String

CurrFileName = OI_FileName.Value
For Each Cell In Range("Description")
    StrFilePaths = Cell.Value
    If CurrFileName = StrFilePaths Then
          Cell.Offset(0, 1).Select
          Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting a different error this time saying - Compile Error: End If without block If. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: My fault.  The formatting threw me off.  I've updated the code.  Either do the above or just remove the "End IF" line.

Comment: I really appreciate your assistance with this. Unfortunately, fixing one issue has generated another. I got a "Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch" this time, and the Debug highlighted the "Case Is =...." line.

Comment: I should have looked more closely at this code before answering.  I assumed more of it worked.  See edit.

Comment: My apologies, I am a 1st time coder, and I think I've bitten off more that I can chew with this one. Once again, I thank you for your help, but I'm still getting "Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch", but this time its on the "StrFilePaths = ........" line.

Comment: Again, I should be reading this more closely.  I'm scanning it while I'm at work.  I think the above edit is a lot closer.  The Case statement doesn't seem to be needed.

Answer (score 0):

1st, Thank you for your considerable input OpiesDad, It took some tweaking, but I think I've got it doing what I want it to do now. I had to simplify and bring the hyperlinks into the Range("Description") column, but I can live with that.

The code as it is right now is:

```
    Private Sub Open_Button_Click()

    Dim StrFilePaths As String
    Dim CurrFileName As String

    CurrFileName = OI_FileName.Value

        Range("Description").Activate
            For Each Cell In Range("Description")
                StrFilePaths = Cell.Value
                If CurrFileName = StrFilePaths Then
                    Cell.Select
                    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
                End If
            Next

    End Sub
```

Thank you again, I really can't thank you enough.

Comment: No problem.  I made an edit on my answer that should allow you to have the hyperlinks in the column next to your range.  Instead of "ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Select..." it needed to be "Cell.Offset(0,1).Select"  I'm glad you got it to work.